# Coinbase / Web3 - how are they connected? Where is my balance on Web3

Tags: web3js, transactions, wallets, transfer, send

I am brand new. I created a Coinbase Account and started investing. I heard someone say something about web3. I don't know what this is, but I think i have money in there. As I'm still waiting to be able to transfer my crypto to my hard wallet, I noticed my available transfer amount keeps decreasing. 1st day i tried to send, $4.04 available balance vs. the $47 I want too. The next day $3.46 available funds to transfer, and now it' $2.97 and said: Available balance calculation is your balance equal to your XRP balance minus your unavailable balance and your web3 wallets. Ummm  What? and why when I have 1 day left to send to my wallet would my available funds to send be lowering. Am I losing on an investment I don't know about? What is web3 - the new internet explorer?  Lastly, why do I have to wait so long to send to my wallet in that 5 days...I could have lost my money.

Comment: Hey, you should verify that you really have an account with Coinbase, as outside the organic nature of falling asset prices reducing an account balance that doesn't sound like my experience with them. Scam?

Seems web3 in the context it has been given here just means 'on chain'.
Coinbase is an exchange with an off chain account "wallet", but also has a self custody "wallet" product called Coinbase wallet (for on chain activity). Coinbase additionally offer some "easy web3" experiences through their exchange, so without clarifying details it's impossible to give any definitive answers.

Comment: https://hbr.org/2022/05/what-is-web3
This is an article to learn what is web3

Answer (score 0):

**Web3** is just a term that refers to the newest evolution of the internet, through use of Cryptocurrencies, decentralized networks, token-based economics and blockchain technology. You can read more about it and why it is important [here](https://ethereum.org/en/web3/).

**[Coinbase](https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/getting-started/crypto-education/what-is-coinbase)** is a [Centralized Exchange](https://www.ledger.com/academy/topics/crypto/what-is-a-centralized-cryptocurrency-exchange-cex#:%7E:text=%E2%80%94%20Centralized%20Exchanges%20(CEXs)%20are,order%20books%20to%20facilitate%20trades.) that allows users to buy, sell, and trade cryptocurrencies.

The only reason the dollar value of your account would be steadily decreasing is if the assets you are holding are decreasing in value, or if you are slowly withdrawing amounts.

Considering your situation, it seems unlikely that the tokens on your account are being steadily withdrawn in small increments, leaving me to believe that you are holding volatile currencies that may just be simply losing value.

For example you said you are holding `XRP`, here is a price chat of `XRP`:

[image]

At the time I'm writing this, for the last month, `XRP` has dropped in value by 25%~.

As to why part of your balance may be labeled `unavailable`, [Coinbase](https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/trading-and-funding/sending-or-receiving-cryptocurrency/available-balance-faq) sometimes will put a hold on your balance if they suspect you of suspicious activity or are trying to verify the validity of your transactions with the bank associated with the card you used to fund the account.

If your funds are still `unavailable` after a couple days with no explanation as to why, I would contact **Coinbase** customer support and explain your issue to them.